# uncaught type error object does not have a kinetic method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

i get error - uncaught type error object does not have a kinetic method
on $('#body').kinetic(
here 'body' is the id of div
following is the code;

```
    // Implement drag & scroll the window behavior
        if ($.browser.msie == null) {
            $('#body').kinetic({
                moved: function (settings) {
                    if (!window.dragging) {
                        $(window).scrollLeft($(window).scrollLeft() + settings.scrollLeft);
                        $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + settings.scrollTop);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Presumably you're using jQuery and [jQuery kinetic](http://the-taylors.org/jquery.kinetic/) here?

Comment: Richard you are right, i am using jQuery and jQuery kinetic

Comment: And are you sure you've loaded them both before this code is executed?

Comment: Thanks Richard. got the solution. jquery kinetic was not loading. thanks.

Comment: No worries, glad to have helped.